# Keep history of old page

Tags: asp.net

I am running some stored procedure and on the basis of that i am doing some calculation and then display their counts and their images on the basis of the data.

then I have each button where I am moving forward with that Detailed data.

Now If I want to come back on this page with the old data then what should I do?

I have been already tried history.back(-1) or history.back() etc.. It will take me back but not with data and only with the control.

I need to come back with the data.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this data the same for all users or based on user input? If the former you could use the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) to store the values, if the latter you could use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

save it to Session.

and in the PageLoad - Reload it from the Session.

Answer (score 0):

history.back() just tells the browser to navigate back to a previous page... the *exact* page the browser originally saw (i.e. it will not fetch it from the server again with possibly changed data).

It's better to navigate *forward* to the page when you want to see it again with updated values.  Redisplay the page when you revisit it, this time with the appropriate data.  As Royi suggests, you can save that data in the [Session](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/).

Answer (score 0):

You could always load the detailed data into the current page with an AJAX call when you click your details button. This way you preserve the state of the original page. 
When navigating "back" just unhide the div that contains the initial view of the data.